# Gatsby v4 - Joining Author Details Into a Post

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Using Gatsby v4. In my blog posts there is a field *author*. There is a separate authors file which includes details of the blog post authors - full name and avatar.

Post File:

```
---
date: "2021-12-31"
title: "Happy New Year"
author: chuck
---
## Happy New Year!
```

**content/authors/author.yaml**

```
- id: chuck
  name: Chuck Norris
  avatar: chuck.jpg
```

The GraphQL looks like this:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
    query($slug: String!) {
        markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
            html
            excerpt(pruneLength: 200)
            frontmatter {
                title
                author {
                    id
                    name
                    avatar
                },
            }
            fields {
                slug
                readingTime {
                    minutes
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But in the BlogPost template the `data.markdownRemark.frontmatter.author` is `null`.

In gatsby-config.js I have:

```
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
            options: {
                path: `${__dirname}/content/authors`,
                name: `authors`
            }
        },
```

and

```
    mapping: {
        'MarkdownRemark.frontmatter.author': `AuthorYaml`
    }
```

But it doesn't help. Same code used to work on Gatsby v2 and stops working with conversion to v4.

Comment: are you using slice machine?

Comment: No, but it turns out there was a typo in a different place that causes this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a typo in a different place that causes this.